# what does a separator of (/ /) mean?

Tags: ruby

Looking at the docs for String's split method, I encountered the separator

> **/ /**

is this a white space separator? why did the returned array contain ***""*** values?

[splitting a string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-)

```
"now's the time".split(/ /) #=> ["", "now's", "", "the", "time"]
```

Comment: 1.9.3. i executed from irb and got the exact results as you did. relied on the documentation and did not even bother to check the results myself. weird that the docu's result set showed "" values

Comment: Your string, and the string in the documentation, differ.  The string in the documentation is `" now's  the time"`.  Note the space before "now" and two spaces before "the" (for some reason, the comment is compressing the two spaces before "the" into a single space).

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes..exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html)

> A Regexp holds a regular expression, used to match a pattern against strings. Regexps are created using the **`/.../`** and **`%r{...}`** literals, and by the **`Regexp::new`** constructor.

---

> is this a white space separator?

As **@Wayne Conrad** mentioned - A whitespace character : `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`. To match white space, the regexp would be using `\s` instead of a **space**.

No it is not a white space separator, rather it is a ***single space***. Use [`Regexp#source`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-source) to confirm the same.

> **Returns the original string of the pattern.**

```
 / /.source # =>  " " 
/ /.source.count(' ') # => 1
```

Here is my `IRB` result :

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > "now's the time".split(/ /)
 => ["now's", "the", "time"]
```

Comment: "single white space" - It is a _single space_.  _White space_ includes characters such as tab and cr.  To match white space, the regexp would be using \s instead of a space.